# How to stop blur() event function to trigger twice?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am trying to fetch the records from the database using blur  function. There are two input fields where this function triggers. I have used different names, variables, javascript, controller using laravel to fetch the records. I am able to fetch the records through ajax and successfully opens the modal. When the modal pop ups when the blur function triggers, it also triggers the function for the second field.

I just want to trigger the modal according to the field, where the blur triggers and not to trigger twice.

```
//input field: originS

<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function(){
          var  origin = "";
          var _token = "";
          var ovalue = "";
        $('#originS').blur(function(){
           ovalue = "";
           origin = $(this).val();
           _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
          $.ajax({
              type: 'POST',
              url: '{{ route('pagescontroller.fetchOrigin') }}',
              data:{origin:origin, _token:_token},
              success: function(response){

                if(response){
                $("#originSelect").modal('show');
                console.log(response);
                $(".result").html(response);

                 $(document).on('change', '#selectSuburb', function () {

                    ovalue =   $(this).val();
                   if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
                   $('#originS').val(ovalue);
                   $("#originSelect").modal('hide');
                   $this.die('blur');
                 }

                 });

                 $('#originSelect').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                       if (ovalue == "") {
                       $("#originS").val('');
                       $(".result").html(response);
                      }
                 });


               }
              },
          });
        });
        });
        </script>

//input field: destS

    </script>

    <script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
    var  dest = "";
    var _token = "";
    var dvalue = "";
    $('#destS').blur(function(){
      dvalue = "";
      dest = $(this).val();
       _token = $('input[name="_token"]').val();
      $.ajax({
          type: 'POST',
          url: '{{ route('pagescontroller.fetchdest') }}',
          data:{dest:dest, _token:_token},
          success: function(response){
            if(response){
            $("#destSelect").modal('show');
            console.log(response);
            $(".dresult").html(response);

             $(document).on('change', '#selectSuburbdest', function () {

                dvalue =   $(this).val();
               if ($(this).is(':checked')) {
               $('#destS').val(dvalue);
               $("#destSelect").modal('hide');
               $this.die('blur');
             }

             });

             $('#destSelect').on('hidden.bs.modal', function (e) {
                   if (dvalue == "") {
                   $("#destS").val('');
                   $(".dresult").html(response);
                  }
             });


           }
          },
      });
    });
    });
    </script>
```

Comment: It's not the blur firing twice, but every blur adds a new change listener to the document, and a new hidden.bs.modal event(?) on `#destSelect`.

Comment: so then what should i trigger with then?

Comment: Just don't attach event listeners inside an event listener, if you don't have a corresponding listener, which removes a listener too.